# how to write image to request body

Tags: go

I have a jpeg `image.Image` and I want to `decode` to a request body. Simplified below, it doesn't seem to finish the request ever. The program hangs.

```
  r, w := io.Pipe()
  jpeg.Encode(w, img, &jpeg.Options{ 80 })

  req, e := http.NewRequest("PUT", myUrl, r)
  if e != nil {
    return nil, e
  }
  http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
```

How can I write an image to the request body?

Comment: I think is because you don't close the reader ?
why are you using io.Pipe ?

Comment: You say you want to `deocde`, bit you're example is encoding a jpeg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a buffer

```
var w bytes.Buffer

jpeg.Encode(&w, img, &jpeg.Options{80})

req, e := http.NewRequest("PUT", myUrl, &w)
if e != nil {
    log.Fatal(e)
}
http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
```

Answer (score 1):

`jpeg.Encode` can't procede, because it's blocked writing to the pipe (pipes don't buffer).

You either need to buffer the encoded image, or run the Encode and http request concurrently.

```
// make sure to buffer this channel, so the goroutine can exit if we return early
errChan := make(chan error, 1)

r, w := io.Pipe()
go func() {
    errChan <- jpeg.Encode(w, img, &jpeg.Options{80})
}()

req, err := http.NewRequest("PUT", myUrl, r)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

// check for an encoding error
err := <-errChan
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```